# Error: Type mismatch in argument 'res' at (1); passed TYPE(matrix) to TYPE(matrix)

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran

I discovered following compiling error:

```
./src/MathModule.f90:85.18: call ReadMatrix(M1)
              1

Error: Type mismatch in argument 'res' at (1); passed TYPE(matrix) to TYPE(matrix)
```

I have declared `Type(Matrix)` in MathModule.f90 and I am simply passing a variable of `Type(Matrix)` in MathModule.f90 to a function declared in another module which uses as input `Type(Matrix)`

Any ideas?

The MathModule.f90 file:

```
module MathModule
use HelpModule
use InputOutputModule
implicit none
private
save

public Full, MatProd, Matrix, dp, MatrixProduct, SVD, Solve, maxerror, pi

! Defines IEEE Double Precision: 53 fractionbits ~= 15.995 decimal digits.
integer, parameter :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15)   
! Defines the error to check floatingpoint equality on.
real(dp) :: maxerror = 0.0000001
! Defines pi with max precision possible.
real(dp), parameter :: pi = 4.0*atan(1.0)

! Defines the Matrix type:
!   A matrix can contain matrices A, B and M.
!   A and B are the lowrank representation and M is the fullrank representation.
!   The dimensions are of M.
!   The rank is of A and B and is -1 for a full matrix. 
type Matrix
    real(dp), allocatable :: A(:,:), B(:,:), M(:,:)
    integer :: rowDimension, columnDimension, rank
end type

contains


! Subroutine to setup the environment for the full command. After the setup, the
! subroutine calls the subroutines necessary for this command. After all operations are
! done, everything is teared down properly.
! @post For correct input at stdin this matrix is converted into a full matrix at stdout.
! @error If the matrix at stdin is not a rank-k matrix the help will be displayed.
subroutine Full()
    type(Matrix) :: Mat

    call ReadMatrix(Mat)
    if(Mat%rank == -1) then
        ! If rank = -1 then the matrix at stdin is not a rank-k matrix.
        call PrintHelp('The matrix at stdin is not a rank-k matrix!')
    else
        ! First allocate the full matrix of Mat, calculate it, set the
        ! rank to -1 (now Mat is a full matrix) and deallocate A and B
        ! because in write only the full matrix of Mat will be
        ! deallocated.          
        allocate(Mat%M(Mat%rowDimension, Mat%columnDimension))
        call MatrixProduct(Mat%A, Mat%B, Mat%M, 'N', 'T')
        Mat%rank = -1
        deallocate(Mat%A)
        deallocate(Mat%B)           
    endif
    call WriteMatrix(Mat)
end subroutine
```

At call `ReadMatrix(mat)` it goes wrong:

```
subroutine ReadMatrix(res, fromUnit) 
    integer, intent(in), optional :: fromUnit
    type(Matrix) :: res
```

Comment: Could you insert the relevant code, both the bit where the routine is called and the routine itself, please? Make sure you include all the declarations of the variables. Also how and where is the derived type defined?

Comment: I have editted the text

Comment: In a hurry so only time for a hint - how does readmatrix know what a matrix is?

Comment: Readmatrix is in an io module and had use Mathmodule before the impliciet none

Comment: So, I think I found the problem. I put the declarations of type matrix in a separate module. The problem was in the compilation step and not in the code itself. However, tanks fort tour quick responsies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have `type Matrix` also declared on `InputOutputModule` (as you specify that `Readmatrix` is in there, too). 
Therefore, you have the same name for two different types (which coincidentally share the same name and properties).

Simply removing the type declaration from `MathModule` and use the one from `InputOutputModule` should do the trick. In my code, I usually have dedicated modules for types that are shared among several modules.

Comment: I was about to answer much the same thing, but I'll comment here with an addition I was to make.  There are some times when this "duplicate" definition is fine, but this is not one of them.